# Are there any myths of little girls with the head of a wolf?

Tags: mythical-creatures, myth-identification

I keep seeing a girl with the head of a wolf, with red eyes, and long hair.

As I'm a very impressionable person I probably saw an image in a mythology book, or a movie, and I can't get this girl out of my head, so now when I'm in a dark room I see this image. It's not a cute kind of girl, it's a scary monster in the dark kind of girl.

Is there such a creature in any mythology? This creature could be a part of a pack, or something, as I think I have seen an adult version of this as well.

Answer (score 5):

Tracking down which creature you saw might be difficult - humans with canine heads is surprisingly common in mythology, though often described as a dog head rather than a wolf.

From ancient Cynocephali tribes ([THE KYNOKEPHALOI](http://www.theoi.com/Phylos/Kunokephaloi.html))  whose name literally means dog-head in ancient greek, to relatively recent urban legends ([Michigan Dogman (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michigan_Dogman)),
from the friendly [Scottish wulver](http://www.scotclans.com/the-scottish-wulver-the-kindly-werewolf/) to the less friendly islanders described by Marco Polo: ([The Travels of Marco Polo/Book 3/Chapter 13](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Travels_of_Marco_Polo/Book_3/Chapter_13)).

I couldn't find references to little girls specifically, but in terms of women there's the [Telkhines](http://www.theoi.com/Pontios/Telkhines.html) but since I struggled to find any art, I doubt that's what you're looking for. If you are able to remember where you saw it we might be able to help more.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
sorry I can't remember any more details, the weird thing is, I can't remember where I saw the image, I know I didn't make it up, because it isn't in any way vague, it's clear and highDef.

Comment: @SpartakShahbazyan remembering something in vivid detail doesn't mean it's a real memory. A quick google search of the term "false memories" should suffice.